# Form submission using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

i have used following javascript to submit a form, In that script, if i remove the alert()  mean, the form doesnot submit. with the alerts box only form submits. how can i resolve the problem

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function caless(id)
    {

    document.formname.page.value=id;
    document.formname.submit();
    alert('');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try replacing `alert('')` with `return`

Comment: The problem likely has something to do with how you are calling the function. You haven't show us a complete test case.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this code is called from within a link onclick? In such case, change to:

```
function caless(id)
{
    document.formname.page.value=id;
    document.formname.submit();
    return false;
}
```

Then in the onclick:

```
<a ... onclick="return caless(id);">
```